# NumPy: apply vector-valued function to mesh grid

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to do something like the following in NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x):
  return x[0] + x[1]

X1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X2 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = np.meshgrid(X1, X2)

result = np.vectorize(f)(X)
```

with the expected result being `array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])`, but it returns the following error:

```
      2 
      3 def f(x):
----> 4   return x[0] + x[1]
      5 
      6 X1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

This is because it tries to apply `f` to all 18 scalar elements of the mesh grid, whereas I want it applied to 9 pairs of 2 scalars. What is the correct way to do this?

**Note:** I am aware this code will work if I do not vectorize `f`, but this is important because `f` can be any function, e.g. it could contain an if statement which throws value error without vectorizing.

Comment: You can still build boolean checks into vectorized functions. `np.vectorize` is literally just a for loop and you seem to understand that so what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @ddejohn The code runs fine without vectorization as I noted but after vectorizing it throw the index error. I'm looking for a way around that

Comment: Except you aren't actually vectorizing anything when you use `np.vectorize` -- it is the exact opposite of vectorization. It's a horribly named function. What I'm trying to tell you is that you should NOT be trying to find a way around getting an error with `np.vectorize` -- you should be trying to find a way around using `np.vectorize`.

Comment: Please share some examples of the types of functions you're hoping to use, as so far it doesn't sound like there's any reason you can't use REAL vectorization.

Comment: For example if `f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] if x[0] > 0 else 0` then `f(X)` throws value error

Comment: The key point with `np.vectorize` is that it passes scalar elements of the arguments.  It's meant for functions that only accept scalars, e.g. `def foo(x,y); return x+y`.  If you have any problems with it, add a diagnostic print to the function to see exactly what it.  Don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist to use [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) you need to define `signature` when defining vectorize on function.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x[0] + x[1]
    # Or
    # return np.add.reduce(x, axis=0)


X1 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X2 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = np.meshgrid(X1, X2)

# np.asarray(X).shape -> (2, 3, 3)
# shape of the desired result is (3, 3)

f_vec = np.vectorize(f, signature='(n,m,m)->(m,m)')
result = f_vec(X)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Nice! I will mark your answer since it technically answers the question, however I am also interested in the case where the input to `f` has arbitrarily high dimension (e.g. `f = lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2]`) which would seem to require `signature='(n,m,m,m)->(m,m,m)'`, and I may not know the dimension a priori

Comment: @mdnestor, for the higher dimensions you can use `numpy.ufunc.reduce` and here `ufunc` == `add`

Comment: `np.vectorize` with `signature` is even slower.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thank you for your advice, But op says, he/she wants to use `np.vectorise`. Can we solve the op's problem without `signature`?

Comment: Signature occasionally is useful, but it actually reduces the broadcasting power of the plain `np.vectorize`.  ``np.vectorize` is best when the function takes several arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For the function you mentioned in the comments:

```py
f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] if x[0] > 0 else 0
```

You can use `np.where`:

```py
def f(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, x[0] + x[1], 0)
    # np.where(some_condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Numpy was designed with vectorization in mind -- unless you have some crazy edge-case there's almost always a way to take advantage of Numpy's broadcasting and vectorization. I strongly recommend seeking out vectorized solutions before giving up so easily and resorting to using `for` loops.

Comment: While there may be alternate ways to write the example function, ultimately `f` is a user-provided parameter (akin to an ODE solver), so it should be as general as possible. this was the reason I used vectorize

Comment: *What* should be as general as possible? Your comment doesn't really make sense. You can still pass functions as parameters to other functions... Are you saying the user provides some kind of string input that you're trying to parse into a valid Python expression?

Comment: As an analogy, `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` also throws a value error if the `func` parameter contains an if statement, but wrapping the function in `np.vectorize` solves it.

Comment: Right, but I've just given you an example of how you can write an equivalent function without needing `if`, by using the `np.where` function...

Answer (score -1):

If you are too lazy, or ignorant, to do are "proper" 'vectorization', you can use `np.vectorize`.  But you need to take time to really read its docs. It isn't magic.  It can be useful, especially if you need to take advantage of broadcasting, and the function, some reason or other, only accepts scalars.

Rewriting your function to work with scalar inputs (though it also works fine with arrays, in this case):

```
In [91]: def foo(x,y): return x+y
    ...: f = np.vectorize(foo)
```

With scalar inputs:

```
In [92]: f(1,2)
Out[92]: array(3)
```

With 2 arrays (a (2,1) and (3,)), returning a (2,3):

```
In [93]: f(np.array([1,2])[:,None], np.arange(1,4))
Out[93]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Samething with `meshgrid`:

```
In [94]: I,J = np.meshgrid(np.array([1,2]), np.arange(1,4),indexing='ij')

In [95]: I
Out[95]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])

In [96]: J
Out[96]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [97]: f(I,J)
Out[97]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Or meshgrid arrays as defined in [93]:

```
In [98]: I,J = np.meshgrid(np.array([1,2]), np.arange(1,4),indexing='ij', sparse=True)

In [99]: I,J
Out[99]: 
(array([[1],
        [2]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3]]))
```

But in a true vectorized sense, you can just add the 2 arrays:

```
In [100]: I+J
Out[100]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

The first paragraph of `np.vectorize` docs (my emphasis):

> Define a vectorized function which takes a **nested sequence of objects or
> numpy** arrays as inputs and returns a single numpy array or a tuple of numpy
> arrays. The vectorized function evaluates `pyfunc` over successive tuples
> of the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
> **broadcasting rules** of numpy.

### edit

Starting with a function that expects a 2 element tuple, we could add a cover that splits it into two, and apply `vectorize` to that:

```
In [103]: def foo1(x): return x[0]+x[1]
     ...: def foo2(x,y): return foo1((x,y))
     ...: f = np.vectorize(foo2)

In [104]: f(1,2)
Out[104]: array(3)
```

`X` is a 2d element tuple:

```
In [105]: X = np.meshgrid(np.array([1,2]), np.arange(1,4),indexing='ij')

In [106]: X
Out[106]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]])]
```

which can be passed to `f` as:

```
In [107]: f(X[0],X[1])
Out[107]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

But there's no need to slow things down with that iteration.  Just pass the tuple to `foo1`:

```
In [108]: foo1(X)
Out[108]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

In `f = lambda x: x[0] + x[1] if x[0] > 0 else 0` you get the 'ambiguity' valueerror because `if` only works with scalars.  But there are plenty of faster numpy ways of replacing such an `if` step.

Comment: Unfortunately `f` needs to take a single vector input, not multiple inputs.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use `np.vectorize`?  What do you hope to gain, that you can't do with fast compile numpy methods and operators, or plain iteration or indexing?  You do realize that `X` from `meshgrid` is a tuple of n-d arrays (see my [94])

Comment: edits added to the answer